# Skins in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am currently working on dotnetnuke 6.

whenever i am creating a skin for a new portal, the skin file is getting inside Portals/_default/Skins/Skinname.ascx. But the skin file should actually get inside Portals/1/Skinname.ascx.

How to get the skin file inside my portal folder which is created.?

If i go and click the Admin -> Skins -> Select drop down -> It shows few number of skin files. Actually it is listing the skin files which is placed inside Portals/_default/Skins. But i want that drop down to list Portals/1/Skins/. What shall i do?. or should i need to change any settings?

Answer (score 0):

usually you develop your skins in the default portal.  then you package them up and you can install them into an instance of dotnetnuke.  It does not matter for performance where the files are.  However you can assign skin to a specific portal by logging into that portal going to admin --> extensions --> install extension and then install the skin package.  This will install the skin in the portal folder and make that skin only available to that portal.

Answer (score 0):

Under your Portal/1 create a folder "Skins/SkinName", and put your skinname.ascx inside those folder.

Make sure you check "Site" on Skin type, it will load your skin in Dropdownlist.